# Splitting Data Frame in RStudio

Tags: r

I have a dataset like the one below. And I'm trying to group categories 'a' and 'b' and their corresponding rate as a subset A, and group categories 'c' and 'd' and their corresponding rate as a subset B. How should I do this?

```
--------------------------
|  category  |    rate   | 
--------------------------
|      a     |     0.5   | 
--------------------------
|      a     |     0.3   | 
--------------------------
|      b     |     0.2   | 
--------------------------
|      b     |     0.5   | 
--------------------------
|      c     |     0.3   | 
--------------------------
|      c     |     0.2   | 
--------------------------
|      d     |     0.5   | 
--------------------------
|      d     |     0.3   | 
--------------------------
```

Comment: do `split(data, data$category %in% c("a", "b"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr` package,

```
library(dplyr)
data<-data.frame(category=c("a","a","b","b","c","c","d","d"),rate=c(0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3))
A<-data%>%filter(category %in% c("a","b"))
B<-data%>%filter(category %in% c("c","d"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using base R:

```
df
# A tibble: 8 x 2
  category  rate
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 a          0.5
2 a          0.3
3 b          0.2
4 b          0.5
5 c          0.3
6 c          0.2
7 d          0.5
8 d          0.3
A <- subset(df, df$category %in% c('a','b'))
B <- subset(df, df$category %in% c('c','d'))
A
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  category  rate
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 a          0.5
2 a          0.3
3 b          0.2
4 b          0.5
B
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  category  rate
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 c          0.3
2 c          0.2
3 d          0.5
4 d          0.3
```